# how make multiple async/await in javascripts -

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-hooks

I need to Execute one function as a result of another function like as chain.
I explain details on my code below.

```
const setter = async () => {
  //this my first request that puts data in property value work right and get data.
  setPropertyvalue(await (getpropertvalue(slide.slide, 0)));

  const lat2 = parseInt(await return_value(propertyvalue, "geolocation_lat"));
  //upper two const lat2&long2 depend on setpopertyvalue
  const long2 = parseInt(await return_value(propertyvalue, "geolocation_long"));   

  setTimeout(() => { //and this code is running after all/ I consider time
    setGeo({ ...geo, lat: lat2, long: long2 });
  }, 2000);

};

setter(); // put this function in onload event
```

my problem = second part of code isn't work properly they just return NAN value - I think they are running  before first part but I need to run these code after first part ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to set the `propertyValue` to state here, just use it in the next async calls. Also there's no need for `setTimeout` here and the whole function can be simplified as follows:

```
const setter = async () => {
  const propertyValue = await getpropertvalue(slide.slide, 0);

  const lat2 = await return_value(propertyValue, "geolocation_lat");
  const long2 = await return_value(propertyValue, "geolocation_long");

  setGeo({ ...geo, lat: parseInt(lat2), long: parseInt(long2) });
};
```

Comment: I got it - at first I should put data in const then filter it

Answer (score 1):

The process to update [React state](https://linguinecode.com/post/master-react-state-and-props) is asynchronous for performance reasons. That’s why changes don’t feel immediate.

Try this code it's help you

```
const setter = async () => {
  let proertyVal = await (getpropertvalue(slide.slide, 0))
  setPropertyvalue(proertyVal)

  const lat2 = parseInt(await return_value(proertyVal, 'geolocation_lat'))
  const long2 = parseInt(await return_value(proertyVal, 'geolocation_long'))
  //upper two const lat2&long2 depend on setpopertyvalue

  setTimeout(() => { //and this code is running after all/ I consider time
    setGeo({ ...geo, lat: lat2, long: long2 })
  }, 2000);

}
setter(); // put this function in onload event
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `propertyvalue` is assigned when you call `const [propertyvalue, setPropertyvalue] = useState()`.

Your `setter` function has **closed over** that variable.

Next time the component renders you will have a new `propertyvalue` variable with the latest value from the state, but that won't help you here.

---

`await (getpropertvalue(slide.slide, 0))` gives you the value that you want, so store that in a local variable and use that.

```
const updatedPropertyvalue = await (getpropertvalue(slide.slide, 0));
setPropertyvalue(updatedPropertyvalue);
// continue to use updatedPropertyvalue in the rest of the function
```

Comment: wow , that silly bug - get my whole day   TNK U

Answer (score -1):

Ok promises should rather work, with promise each function will have to resolve in order for the next to work.

```
async function todos(){
 await(fetch({url:'',method:''})).
 then((res)=>{}).
 then((res)={}).
 catch((err)=>)
}
```

Comment: They're using promises. They aren't using `fetch`